# Magento2.4: How to get Salable quantity in list.phtml file?

Tags: magento, magento2.4

How can I get salable quantity on list.phtml or category page file, I want to show labels on products with 0 salable quantity.
Are there any other approaches without using object manager?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code in phtml file to get salable qty

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku');
$qty = $StockState->execute($_product->getSku());
echo($qty[0]['qty']);
```

Comment: The use of "Object manager" and deprecated code is strictly prohibited in my company, it's bad practice. I hope you understand.

Comment: Then Create a block class and pass '\Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku' in constructor and create a function to achieve the above.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to get salable QTY.

```
<?php 
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $StockState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface');
    $qty = $StockState->execute($_product->getSku(), 2);
?>
```

Either Object Manager is not a good approach, but you need to inject in your custom module such as:

```
namespace Cloudways\Module\ModelName;
use Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku;
```

Refer Link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301956/how-to-get-salable-qty-in-magento-2-3-3/302187#302187